# Searching email in imap Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I am using imap package in my project I have read the documentation and I found this for searching in email with date.

```
imap.search([ 'UNSEEN', ['SINCE', 'May 20, 2010'] ], function(err, results) {
});
```

I want to search email between two dates for example May 20, 2010 to May 28,2010.

So it possible to find between dates in imap protocol ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you give reference to the module you refer to?

If you are using [mscdex/node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap), you can refer to

> 'BEFORE' - Messages whose internal date (disregarding time and timezone) is earlier than the specified date.
>
> 'SINCE' - Messages whose internal date (disregarding time and timezone) is within or later than the specified date.

in its API documentation https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap/blob/master/README.md#API

> search(< array >criteria, < function >callback) - (void)

so to sum up

```
imap.search([ 'UNSEEN', ['SINCE', 'May 20, 2010'], ['BEFORE', 'May 28, 2010'] ],
    function(err, results) {
});
```

is what you want ...